# batchGet returns 0's when using multiple date ranges for particular account

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am running into a problem with a batchGet query.  I am using the exact same batchGet query on two different GA accounts to query specific data for two date ranges, last month and last month a year ago.  When I run it on one account, I get data back.  However, when I run it on another account, I get nothing but 0's for every column/date range.

If I run two separate queries - one for the current date range, one for the previous date range - I get the data back just fine in both cases.  However, it'd be nice to not have to run two queries when it's possible to get away with one.  **EDIT:** Also, it appears that if I include a dimension in my query, the query returns just fine.  The only problem is with metric-less queries.

I think tbe problem it might have something to do with the fact that there is no GA data in the problematic GA account a year ago - thus maybe the fact that there was no data a year ago is somehow causing today's data to also be 0.  However, to test, I changed the second date range in my working GA account to ten years ago (to force it to return 0's) and I still get proper numbers back - correct numbers for the current date, 0's for the previous one.  So it appears there is some account-specific weirdness going on here.

Here is my request in JSON format:

```
{
   "reportRequests":[
      {
         "viewId":"_my_view_id_",
         "dateRanges":[
            {
               "endDate":"2017-10-31",
               "startDate":"2017-10-01"
            },
            {
               "endDate":"2016-10-31",
               "startDate":"2016-10-01"
            }
         ],
         "metrics":[
            {
               "alias":"users",
               "expression":"ga:users"
            },
            {
               "alias":"sessions",
               "expression":"ga:sessions"
            },
            {
               "alias":"averageSessionDuration",
               "expression":"ga:avgSessionDuration"
            },
            {
               "alias":"pageviews",
               "expression":"ga:pageviews"
            },
            {
               "alias":"avgTimeOnPage",
               "expression":"ga:avgTimeOnPage"
            },
            {
               "alias":"pageViewsPerSession",
               "expression":"ga:pageviewsPerSession"
            },
            {
               "alias":"percentNewSessions",
               "expression":"ga:percentNewSessions"
            },
            {
               "alias":"bounceRate",
               "expression":"ga:bounceRate"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm using the most up-to-date version of the PHP google/apiclient.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using GA360 by chance?  I'm thinking you're hitting a sample threshold. Adding the dimension is forcing GA to use a full query, rather than hitting the pre-aggregated tables. That issue normally only happens for GA360 users so disregard if you're using GA free.

If it is GA360, and you're in fact getting hit with sampling, then you could continue to add your dimension without issue.

Comment: According to my reading of the docs, the response would contain samplesReadCounts and samplingSpaceSizes if there was any sampling going on.  I see neither in either response.

Comment: Hitting preaggregated tables doesn't count as sampling.